# how to remove .so file in android studio?

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0, libs

I have added scanLiabray and OpenCV to my project so I have to add some lib(check-in image).

Now I don't need the above 2 modules so I remove and delete those.

but when I generate APK it still includes those ".so" file

I have removed these files from the libs folder but why those files are still included ".so" file?

I have removed all dependencies related to these libs

Does this file needed for the project by default?

how not to include this ".so" file?

[image: analyze the APK.]

build.gradle

```
...
dependencies{

//    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", excludes: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
//    implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary3410')
//    implementation project(':scanlibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
    implementation files('libs//poi-3.7.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

... other dependencies
}
```

commented dependency I have removed.

Comment: Yash, Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @AnujRaghuvanshi NO